# Download files link from Firebase storage with python

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-storage

It seems there is a huge lack of documentation on firebase python API. What I want to do get a download link of all files in a folder on firebase storage through my Flask app. My latest approach was:

```py
from firebase_admin import storage
bucket = storage.bucket()

blob = bucket.blob('articles/'+aid+'/resources')
server_path = blob.generate_signed_url(datetime.timedelta(seconds=999999999), method='GET')
print(server_path)
```

the problem is that `blob = bucket.blob('articles/'+aid+'/resources')` points to a folder in the storage and when I try to obtain a download link for the folder, the link doesn't work.

Now I could solve this in 2 different ways:

- find a way to zip the folder a then get a download link
- list the files in the folder and then get a download link for each one of them

Unfortunately I cannot find any documentation on how to perform those 2 tasks in python.
PS. I'm already using firebase_admin to initialize my app and I'd rather not switch to pyrebase or other third party libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I read more carefully firebase_admin documentation and it says:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start

> You can use the bucket references returned by the Admin SDK in
>   conjunction with the official Google Cloud Storage client libraries to
>   upload, download, and modify content in the buckets associated with
>   your Firebase projects. Note that you do not have to authenticate
>   Google Cloud Storage libraries when using the Firebase Admin SDK. The
>   bucket references returned by the Admin SDK are already authenticated
>   with the credentials used to initialize your Firebase app.

so I went to google.cloud documentation and I used their code without having to initialize google.cloud storage but just passing as **storage** the firebase_admin one. So to list all objects in your bucket:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects

```
blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs())
```